# Syntax of IF statement Rails 4 with Asset Pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, if-statement, asset-pipeline

I am trying to check if an image file exists in the asset pipeline and if it not there display a default. If it is there I want to display it instead. Where am I going wrong?

```
<% if "#{@person.user_name}.jpg".nil %>
  <%= image_tag("default.gif") %>
<% else %>
  <%= image_tag("#{@person.user_name}.jpg") %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<% unless Rails.application.assets.find_asset("#{@person.user_name}.jpg") %>
     <%= image_tag("default.gif") %>
<% else %>
    <%= image_tag("#{@person.user_name}.jpg") %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: @lostrennie glad it helped !! :)